# Mismatch in keytool and openssl certificate fingerprint

Tags: android, openssl, keytool

I was trying to fingerprint android developer certificates, inside META-INF/, for research purposes.

I'm finding certain scenarios in which output from keytool and openssl would give me different SHA1 fingerprints for the same certificate:

Using keytool:

```
keytool -princert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA
...
    SHA1: 9D:17:FB:AB:67:BB:D0:7B:12:FE:E8:33:7D:66:F1:C4:2B:03:BD:F7
...
```

Using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in META-INF/CERT.RSA -print_certs -out CERT.cert
openssl x509 -in CERT.cert -fingerprint -noout
     SHA1 Fingerprint=80:D5:CD:66:6E:44:75:62:A8:B3:7E:5D:AC:00:DE:1D:FF:6B:E6:CA
```

Is this normal - keytool uses its own way to fingerprint certs, which differs from openssl- , am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug somewhere?

By the way, I'm no expert, so feel free to give any advice, even the the most basic stuff!

If you need an example of this, I can give you the name of an android app in which this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different SHA1 fingerprints are caused by different encodings of the code signing certificate.

The first fingerprint (by keytool) is calculated over the certificate bytes exactly as they are contained in the PKCS#7 file `META-INF/CERT.RSA`. The length of the signature (of the certificate, not the signature of the code) is encoded here in two bytes, where actually one byte would be enough. To see this we have to take a look at the ASN.1 dump of `CERT.RSA`. There are several programs that can do this, but I recommend Peter Gutmann's [dumpasn1/GUIdumpASN](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/). The relevant part is this:

```
    <06 09>
532   9:             OBJECT IDENTIFIER
       :               sha1WithRSAEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 5)
    <05 00>
543   0:             NULL
       :             }
    <03 82 00 81>
545 129:           BIT STRING    
       :             65 26 30 0C 41 32 63 75    e&0.A2cu
       :             2F B7 DF 9A 96 37 72 1B    /....7r.
```

The bytes `82 00 81` are the length bytes of the BITSTRING (which is the signature of the certificate) encoded in the [long form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#The_definite_form).

According to the [Distinguished Encoding Rules DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) the "*shortest possible length encoding must be used*", which would have been `81 81`. This means that the code signing certificate is not completely DER encoded.

When you exported the certificate with openssl, it re-encoded the certificate to valid DER:

```
    <03 81 81>
489 129:   BIT STRING    
        :     65 26 30 0C 41 32 63 75    e&0.A2cu
        :     2F B7 DF 9A 96 37 72 1B    /....7r.
```

Therefore the hash value (fingerprint) of the certificate is different, it has changed.

Neither keytool nor openssl did something wrong. The point of DER encoding is that it generates always exactly the same byte representation of ASN.1 structures.

The software that caused this issue is the tool the faulty code signing certificate was created with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I don't see multiple certificates in the keytool command, I just get the same certificate openssl gets when converting the file, but their fingerprints are different.

Comment: @VdS Can you provide the file CERT.RSA as a download somehow?

Comment: Hi @Omikron, the link is http://sharesend.com/hig38jz0 . I'm having problems with file exchange services right now, if you want it uploaded anywhere else I could do it at night. Thanks!

Comment: So, if keytool is informing incorrectly about the fingerprint, should only openssl be used?

Comment: @VdS I have to take a closer look at the encoding. I am not sure yet, which one is correct. How did you generate the certificate? With OpenSSL?

Comment: I did not generate it, so I can't answer. It's used to sign an android app I came across. By the way, don't know if you're familiar with android, but hashing the output given by packageInfo.signatures (which, actually, gives the public key) will give me the keytool fingerprint. I can give you more details on that if you want.

Comment: So, in the RSA the encoding of the certificate changed. I'm going to accept your answer, since it is right, but I would like more insight if you could give it to me, like for example, do you know why the encoding changed in the RSA? I don't know how this was signed, but I'm guessing it was with jarsigner, is this a normal behaviour of the app or something in the certificate made it change?

Comment: Thank you very much @Omikron! That is a very deep yet understandable answer!